# Transform CSV column by a function using command line tools

Tags: linux, unix, sed, awk

Given a csv file such as

```
h1 h2
a  0
b  1
c  0
```

how to rename `0` to `YES` and `1` to `NO` in the second column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of these:

```
awk 'BEGIN {word[0]="YES"; word[1]="NO"} NR>1 {$2=word[$2]} 1' file
perl -pe 's/(\d)$/ qw(YES NO)[$1] /e if $.>1' file
```

To replace the file, you can use

```
gawk -i inplace '...' file
perl -i -pe '...' file
```

Comment: Thanks! To ask version where instead of 0 we have w and instead of 1 we have v ...

Comment: awk: `BEGIN {word["v"]="something"; word["w"]="something"}` -- need to quote the strings so awk does not try to interpret them as variables.